# What is INF in META-INF and WEB-INF in a Java web application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, acronym

I guess INF stand for infinity but that doesn't make any sense.

What do you think?

p.s.

A [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=What%20is%20INF%20in%20META-INF%20and%20WEB-INF%20in%20a%20Java%20web%20application%3F&oq=What%20is%20INF%20in%20META-INF%20and%20WEB-INF%20in%20a%20Java%20web%20application%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.327j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=What%20is%20INF%20in%20META-INF%20and%20WEB-INF%20in%20a%20Java%20web%20application%3F&newwindow=1&start=10) for this gives us little helpful results and some definition for the two folders. Though I can't find what is INF meant.

> The META-INF directories related to .jar files. They contain the
>   manifest (list of contents) of a jar and are created when you write a
>   jar file...
>
> The WEB-INF directory contains a heirarcy in which you'll find the
>   necessary configuration information for your web application...

Comment: INF == Information .....

Comment: Oh so simple and straightforward! Please put that into an answer to get accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`INF` is an abbreviation for `Information` (not infinity in this case).